# Replacing all occurrence after nth occurrence in a line in perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I need to replace all occurrences of a string after nth occurrence in every line of a Unix file.

My file data:

```
:account_id:12345:6789:Melbourne:Aus
:account_id:98765:43210:Adelaide:Aus
```

My output data:

```
:account_id:123456789MelbourneAus
:account_id:9876543210AdelaideAus
```

tried using sed: `sed 's/://3g' test.txt`

Unfortunately, the `g` option with the occurrence is not working as expected. instead, it is replacing all the occurrences.

Comment: looking specifically for perl as I have a series of perl commands to incorporate. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify you record structure? Based on what you've given us, I think I probably _wouldn't_ use regex for this job, but rather something using `split`.

Comment: I don't get it. The `sed` command you gave works exactly as your question as well as the answer given so far. Or may be your wording isn't right, did you try the `sed` command with `GNU sed` or some other version?

Comment: I am running it on an AIX server. which mostly does not support GNU sed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nag yeah, I think you don't have GNU sed, it is better to mention AIX in your questions

Comment: Why tag the question with awk and sed if you want a perl solution as you say in your subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `perl` solution like

```sh
perl -pe 's~^(?:[^:]*:){2}(*SKIP)(?!)|:~~g if /^:account_id:/' test.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0dSm0g) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/siX0qe/1).

The `^(?:[^:]*:){2}(*SKIP)(?!)|:` regex means:

- `^(?:[^:]*:){2}(*SKIP)(?!)` - match

  - `^` - start of string (here, a line)
  - `(?:[^:]*:){2}` - two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than a `:` and then a `:` char
  - `(*SKIP)(?!)` - skip the match and go on to search for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `:` - match a `:` char.

And only run the replacement if the current line starts with `:account_id:` (see `if /^:account_id:/'`).

Or an `awk` solution like

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=":"} /^:account_id:/ {result="";for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { result = result (i > 2 ? $i : $i OFS)}; print result}' test.txt
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/j8XI3C). Details:

- `BEGIN{OFS=FS=":"}` - sets the input/output field separator to `:`
- `/^:account_id:/` - line must start with `:account_id:`
- `result=""` - sets `result` variable to an empty string
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { result = result (i > 2 ? $i : $i OFS)}; print result}` - iterates over the fields and if the field number is greater than `2`, just append the current field value to `result`, else, append the value + output field separator; then print the `result`.

Comment: I want to do this is the line starts with ":account_id" only. There are lines which begins with ":customer_id" as well.

Comment: @nag I updated both the `perl` and `awk` solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach using `awk`

```
awk -v c=':' -v n=2 'BEGIN{
                       FS=OFS=""
                     }
                     {
                       j=0;
                       for(i=0; ++i<=NF;)
                         if($i==c && j++>=n)$i=""
                     }1' file
```

```
$ cat file 
:account_id:12345:6789:Melbourne:Aus
:account_id:98765:43210:Adelaide:Aus

$ awk -v c=':' -v n=2 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{j=0;for(i=0; ++i<=NF;)if($i==c && j++>=n)$i=""}1' file 
:account_id:123456789MelbourneAus
:account_id:9876543210AdelaideAus
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `awk`, using `gensub` please try following. This is completely  based on your shown samples, where OP wants to remove `:` from 3rd occurrence onwards. Using `gensub` to segregate parts of matched values and removing all colons from 2nd part(from 3rd colon onwards) in it as per OP's requirement.

```
awk -v regex="^([^:]*:)([^:]*:)(.*)" '
{
  firstPart=restPart=""
  firstPart=gensub(regex, "\\1 \\2", "1", $0)
  restPart=gensub(regex,"\\3","1",$0)
  gsub(/:/,"",restPart)
  print firstPart restPart
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

I have inferred based on the limited data you've given us, so it's possible this won't work. But I wouldn't use regex for this job. What you have there is colon delimited fields.

So I'd approach it using `split` to extract the data, and then some form of string formatting to reassemble exactly what you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ( undef, $first, @rest ) = split /:/; 
  print ":$first:", join ( "", @rest ),"\n";
}

__DATA__
:account_id:12345:6789:Melbourne:Aus
:account_id:98765:43210:Adelaide:Aus
```

This gives you the desired result, whilst IMO being considerably clearer for the next reader than a complicated regex.

Answer (score 3):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way if *n* fixed and equal 2 following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
:account_id:12345:6789:Melbourne:Aus
:account_id:98765:43210:Adelaide:Aus
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=""}{$2=FS $2 FS;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
:account_id:123456789MelbourneAus
:account_id:9876543210AdelaideAus
```

Explanation: use `:` as field separator and nothing as output field separator, this itself does remove all `:` so I add `:` which have to be preserved: 1st (before second column) and 2nd (after second column). Beware that I tested it solely for this data, so if you would want to use it you should firstly test it with more possible inputs.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:/\n/3;h;s/://g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Replace the third occurrence of `:` by a newline.

Make a copy of the line.

Delete all occurrences of `:`'s.

Append the amended line to the copy.

Join the two lines by removing everything from third occurrence of the copy to the third occurrence of the amended line.

N.B. The use of the newline is the best delimiter to use in the case of sed, as the line presented to seds commands are initially devoid of newlines. However the important property of the delimiter is that it is unique and therefore can be any such character as long as it is not found anywhere in the data set.

An alternative solution uses a loop to remove all `:`'s after the first two:

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(([^:]*:){2}[^:]*):/\1/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(:[^:]+:)(.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] gensub(/:/,"","g",a[2]) } 1' file
:account_id:123456789MelbourneAus
:account_id:9876543210AdelaideAus
```

and with any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/:[^:]+:/){ tgt=substr($0,1+RLENGTH); gsub(/:/,"",tgt); $0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH) tgt } 1' file
:account_id:123456789MelbourneAus
:account_id:9876543210AdelaideAus
```